# Different category URLs for store views, redirect to proper one

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, seo, redirect-url

I would like to have different URL keys for a category for every store view.
ex `http://store.com/electronics.html` for `EN` store

`http://store.com/electronics-gr.html` for a `GR` view.

When i switch store views when inside the category it properly redirects me to the correct one. If however i have my website on the `GR` store view and i click a link outside of my shop `http://store.com/electronics.html` that will throw a 404 not found.

Only solution i could come up with was each time a category is saved to create a `301 Redirect` for say `/electronics.html` to `/electronics-gr.html` for the `GR` store view and so on.

Before going on through i would like some feedback, if there is some other solution i could go with?

Comment: Which Magento version you're in?

Comment: Magento 2, sorry for not mentioning

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127076/magento-2-how-to-redirect-customer-to-specific-store-view-according-to-browser-l

Comment: it points me in a good direction, i'll try and work something around it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://pastebin.com/2DfYkUEj

Came up with this. The `const` are just a temp solution but it looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i also faced this issue Above (Magento 2.2.3) Version while using Language Switcher.

Please follow below code to resolved this issue of redirection while changing language switcher :

- First of all override the file 'vendor/magento/module-url-rewrite/Model/StoreSwitcher/RewriteUrl.php'  and Replace below code.

From line No. 67 to 77

```
if ($oldRewrite) {
            // look for url rewrite match on the target store
            $currentRewrite = $this->urlFinder->findOneByData([
                UrlRewrite::REQUEST_PATH => $urlPath,
                UrlRewrite::STORE_ID => $targetStore->getId(),
            ]);
            if (null === $currentRewrite) {
                /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response */
                $targetUrl = $targetStore->getBaseUrl();
            }
        }
```

To

```
 if ($oldRewrite) {

        $currentRewrites = $this->urlFinder->findAllByData([
            UrlRewrite::TARGET_PATH => $oldRewrite->getTargetPath(),
            UrlRewrite::STORE_ID => $targetStore->getId(),
        ]);

        if (null === $currentRewrites || empty($currentRewrites)) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response */
            $targetUrl = $targetStore->getBaseUrl();
        } else {
            foreach($currentRewrites as $rewrite) {
                $targetUrl = $targetStore->getBaseUrl() . $rewrite->getRequestPath();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I Hope this is Helpful to You.

Thanks.