# Not redirecting depending on the storeview code

Tags: magento2, store-view, magento-2.1.9, redirect-url, rma

We have different store views: Spanish (es_es), French (fr_fr) and English (en). And we have a RMA extension where you can create them. Once you create a RMA you redirect to the same RMA page; we assume it works for the english storeview because of the code of the storeview is "en", not like the spanish and the french ones which have respectively (es_es) and (fr_fr) which redirect to the homepage.

**This is the condition that redirects:**

```
if ($result[0] == self::HTTP_CODE_OK) {
                                $this->sendEmailSuccessCreateRma($result[1]);
                                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('RMA was created successfully'));
                                $this->_redirect('sap/rma/index');
                            } else {
                                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($result[1]);
}
```

**And this statement in the phtml:**

```
<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="primary">
        <button type="submit" class="action primary" data-role="rma-submit">
            <span><?= __('Submit Request') ?></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

We have tried doing another class class like:

`\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager`

with this code:

```
$url = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('sap/rma/index');
$this->_redirect($url);
```

But it leaves us a blank page and we can't see anything wrong in the logs.

Comment: Have you try using responsefactory?

Comment: No, didn't know it existed. How should I do it?

Comment: Please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127076/magento-2-how-to-redirect-customer-to-specific-store-view-according-to-browser-l?noredirect=1&lq=1
if it can help you